# SQL - Incorrect Use of Union and Order BY

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT Count(STATUS),
   STATUS,
   ROUND(Count(STATUS) * 100 /
           (SELECT Count(*)
            FROM call_view
            WHERE (create_month = Month(Now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
              AND (create_year = Year(Now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
              AND customer_company_name = "Company" ), 1) AS Percentage
FROM call_view
WHERE (create_month = Month(Now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
AND (create_year = Year(Now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
AND customer_company_name = "Company"
GROUP BY STATUS
ORDER BY COUNT(CALL_ID) DESC LIMIT 6
UNION
SELECT Sum(category_count),
   'Other',
   sum(percentage)
FROM
( SELECT Count(CATEGORY) AS category_count,
       COUNT(CALL_ID),
       CATEGORY,
       ROUND(Count(CATEGORY) * 100 /
               (SELECT Count(*)
                FROM call_view
                WHERE (create_month = Month(Now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
                  AND (create_year = Year(Now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
                  AND customer_company_name = "Company" ), 1) 
AS Percentage FROM call_view
WHERE (create_month = Month(Now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
  AND (create_year = Year(Now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
  AND customer_company_name = "Company"
GROUP BY CATEGORY
ORDER BY COUNT(CALL_ID) DESC LIMIT 6,
                                  1525125215) AS original_query
```

I got the Error "Incorrect Use of UNION And ORDER BY".

I am using this query for a tool and I need it to work.

I know there is a solution, where you can use Parathesis() at the beginning and endings of both querys, but I can't use that for my tool.

That's why I need an other solution for this query, instead of using the () solution

Is there  any other solution??

Would appreciate any help... Have this Problem since 2 days....

Cheers

Comment: Are you trying to ORDER BY the complete UNION result? (Or just one of the selects?)

Comment: The first Query, retrieves the Categories with most Calls ( Place 1-6) I want them to be Order BY DESC. The Seconds Query retrieves all Category under the alias "other". So I want to ORDER BY the first query, and just add the second query at the end of the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(
    SELECT Count(STATUS),  
    STATUS, 
    ROUND(Count(STATUS) * 100 / (SELECT Count(*) 
                                  FROM   call_view 
                                  WHERE 
    ( create_month = Month(Now() - 
                    INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
     AND ( create_year = Year( 
         Now() - INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
     AND customer_company_name = "Company"
       ), 1) AS Percentage
    FROM   call_view 
    WHERE  ( create_month = Month(Now() - INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
    AND ( create_year = Year(Now() - INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
    AND customer_company_name = "Company"
    GROUP BY STATUS
    ORDER BY COUNT(CALL_ID) DESC
    limit 6
)
union
(
    Select Sum(category_count), 'Other', sum(percentage) 
    from (
    SELECT Count(CATEGORY) as category_count,  COUNT(CALL_ID), CATEGORY,

    ROUND(Count(CATEGORY) * 100 / (SELECT Count(*) 
                              FROM   call_view 
                              WHERE 
      ( create_month = Month(Now() - 
                INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
    AND ( create_year = Year( 
      Now() - INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
    AND customer_company_name ="Company"
    ), 1) AS Percentage
    FROM   call_view 
    WHERE  ( create_month = Month(Now() - INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
    AND ( create_year = Year(Now() - INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
       AND customer_company_name = "Company"
       GROUP BY CATEGORY
      ORDER BY COUNT(CALL_ID) DESC
    limit 6, 1525125215) as original_query
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your respone. I already tried this solution and it's working, but the parathesis () cause a problem for another tool at the beginning and ending of both querys. That's why I need a solution without ().

Comment: parentheses are necessary here.

Comment: Isn't there a possiblity to combine both querys (like a Subquery) and don't use the Union operator?